# Multi-Task Learning: Train a neural network to have different loss functions for the two classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a neural net with two loss functions, one is binary cross entropy for the 2 classes, and another is a regression. Now I want the regression loss to be evaluated only for class_2, and return 0 for class_1, because the regressed feature is meaningless for class_1.

How can I implement such an algorithm in Keras?

Training it separately on only class_1 data doesn't work because I get nan loss. There are more elegant ways to define the loss to be 0 for one half of the dataset and `mean_square_loss` for another half?

Comment: This should be re-opened, it's an important question in multi-task learning. @user7867665, you can pass in a binary mask which are 1 or 0 for each of your loss functions, in the same way that you pass in the labels. Then multiply each loss by its corresponding mask. The derivative of `1x` is just `dx`, and the derivative of `0x` is `0`. You end up zeroing out the gradient in the appropriate loss functions. Virtually all optimizers are additive optimizers, meaning you're summing the gradient, adding a zero is a null operation. Your final loss function should be the sum of all your other losses.

Comment: Oh that's an excellent solution! Thanks @DavidParks. I have also reworded the question in the form of something a little more specific. I cannot give a oversimplistic example because it will loose the point (unless someone has a suggestion to improve my question?)

Comment: You want to explicitly use the term "multi-task learning" for these kinds of problems. People were probably not very familiar with it. I'm a huge proponent of multi-task learning though and have applied it in many cases and published papers using it. And I puzzled over this very problem for many days the first time I encountered it.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll make the edit. I wasn't able to find the 'masking' feature but I have just used `sample_weights` to implement what you suggested

Comment: Ah, I don't know much about Keras. Another solution is to change your loss function to use the labels only: L = cross_entropy * (label / (label + 1e-6)). That term will be almost 0 and almost 1. Close enough for government work and neural networks at least. This is what I actually used the first time before I realized it was as simple as multiplying by an array of mask values.

Comment: That was exactly my line of thought, some kind of soft cuts. The masking is working perfectly, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a question that's important in multi-task learning where you have multiple loss functions, a shared neural network structure in the middle, and inputs that may not all be valid for all loss functions.

You can pass in a binary mask which are `1` or `0` for each of your loss functions, in the same way that you pass in the labels. Then multiply each loss by its corresponding mask. The derivative of `1x` is just `dx`, and the derivative of `0x` is `0`. You end up zeroing out the gradient in the appropriate loss functions. Virtually all optimizers are additive optimizers, meaning you're summing the gradient, adding a zero is a null operation. Your final loss function should be the sum of all your other losses.

I don't know much about Keras. Another solution is to change your loss function to use the labels only: `L = cross_entropy * (label / (label + 1e-6))`. That term will be almost 0 and almost 1. Close enough for government work and neural networks at least. This is what I actually used the first time before I realized it was as simple as multiplying by an array of mask values.

Another solution to this problem is to us `tf.where` and `tf.gather_nd` to select only the subset of labels and outputs that you want to compare and then pass that subset to the appropriate loss function. I've actually switched to using this method rather than multiplying by a mask. But both work.

Comment: This solution (of masking) works perfectly for my multi-task learning problem with multiple loss functions! On Keras I implement it with `sample_weight`, but other's might find it even simpler to use `class_weight`